# What are the Command Line options for the VB6 IDE (Compiler)

Tags: vb6

I'm doing batch compiling and need to specify the output directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## VB6

Information directly from running `VB6.exe /?`:

> ### Command Line Options
>
> ```
> VB6[.EXE] [[{/run | /r}] | [/runexit] | [{/make | /m}] projectname] [/out filename] 
>           [/outdir path] [/d const=value{[:constN=valueN]}]
>           [/mdi | /sdi] [{/cmd argument | /c argument}]
> ```
>
> `/run or /r projectname`  Tells Visual Basic to compile `projectname`
> and run it, using the arguments stored in the Command Line Arguments
> field of the Make tab of the Project Properties dialog box.
>
> `/runexit projectname`    Tells Visual Basic to compile `projectname` and
> run it.  Visual Basic will exit when the project returns to design
> mode.
>
> `/make or /m projectname` Tells Visual Basic to compile `projectname`
> and make an executable file from it, using the existing settings
> stored in the project file.
>
> `/out filename`   Specifies a file to receive errors when you build
> using /m or `/runexit`. If you do not use /out, command line build
> errors are displayed in a message box.
>
> `/outdir path`    Specifies a directory path to place all output files in
> when using /make.
>
> `/d or /D const=value...` Tells Visual Basic which values to use for
> conditional compilation constants when making an .EXE or ActiveX
> component with the /make switch.  Separate multiple constants with
> colons.
>
> `/cmd or /c argument` Puts argument in the Command Line Arguments
> field in the Make tab of the Project Properties dialog box. When used,
> this must be the last switch on the command line.
>
> `/mdi` or `/sdi`  Changes the Visual Basic environment to either Single
> Document Interface (SDI) or Multiple Document Interface (MDI) mode.
> Visual Basic remains in this mode until you change it.
>
> You may use a group name in place of `projectname` in any of the above
> switches.

---

Sourced [from here](http://www.whippleware.com/VBLM/webhelp/vblm/vb_command_line_summary.htm) is some additional information which pertains to older versions of VB as well. That external page may eventually disappear.

> ## VB Command Line Summary
>
> ### All Versions
>
> ```
> vb*[.exe] [[{/run | /r} projectname] {/make | /m } projectname]
>           {/cmd argument | /c argument}]
> ```
>
> `projectname` The name of your project (.vbp) file.
>
> `/run` or `/r` Tells Visual Basic to compile and run `projectname` using
> the arguments stored in the Command Line Arguments field of the Make
> tab of the Project Properties dialog box. You can run more than one
> project using this command. Replace `projectname` with
> `projectgroupname`.
>
> `/make` or `/m` Tells Visual Basic to compile `projectname` and make
> an executable (.exe) file, using the existing settings of the `Path`,
> `EXEName`, and `Title` properties of the `APP` object. You can compile and
> make an executable (.exe) file from more than one project using this
> command. Replace of the `projectname` with `projectgroupname`.
>
> `/cmd` or `/c` Puts argument in the Command Line Arguments field in
> the Make tab of the Project Properties dialog box. When used, this
> must be the last switch on the command line.
>
> ### Versions 4 + Only
>
> ```
> vb*[.exe] {/d compileconst} [{/makedll | /l} projectname]
> ```
>
> `/makedll` or `/l` Tells Visual Basic to compile projectname and make
> an in-process ActiveX server (.dll) file from it.
>
> `/d` or `/D` Tells Visual Basic which values to use for conditional
> compilation constants when making an .EXE with the /make switch or an
> ActiveX DLL with the `/makedll` switch.
>
> `compileconst` The names and values of conditional compilation
> constants used in the project file.
>
> ### Version 5+ Only
>
> ```
> vb*[.exe] [{/runexit} projectname][{/m} or {/runexit} projectname /out filename}][{/m}][/sdi] or [/mdi]
> ```
>
> `/runexit` Tells Visual Basic to run projectname. If for any reason
> the file is changed in the process of running, all changes are ignored
> and no dialog appears on exit to design mode.
>
> `filename` The name of the file to receive errors when you build an
> executable using the `/m` or `/runexit` option.
>
> `/out` Allows you to specify a file to receive errors when you build
> using the `/m` or /runexit option. The first error encountered is
> placed in this file with other status information. If you do not use
> the /out option, command line build errors are displayed in a message
> box. This option is useful if you are building multiple projects.
>
> `/?` Lists the available Command Line arguments.
>
> `/sdi` Changes the Visual Basic environment to SDI (Single Document
> Interface) mode. Visual Basic remains in SDI mode until you change it.
> You can change to MDI mode by using the `/mdi` argument or by clearing
> the SDI Development Environment option in the Advanced tab of the
> Options dialog box.
>
> `/mdi` Opens Visual Basic in MDI (Multiple Document Interface) mode.
> Visual Basic remains in MDI mode until you change it. You can change
> to SDI mode by using the `/sdi` argument or by selecting the SDI
> Development Environment option in the Advanced tab of the Options
> dialog box. MDI mode is the default.

Answer (score 22):

`/run`

`/runexit`    - Compile and then run it.  Exit VB IDE when project returns to design mode.

`/make` or `/m` projectname  - compiles an makes exe using the existing settings in proj file

`/out` filename

`/outdir` path   Specifies a directory path to place all output files in when using `/make`

`/d`

`/cmd`

`/mdi` or `/sdi`

... and a couple of others.

Run `vb6.exe /?` for more information.

Comment: This doesn't explain what most of them do

Answer (score 7):

A bit of Google work suggests that such a list of options can be obtained by going to the directory containing vb6.exe in Command Prompt and running

```
vb6.exe /?
```

Answer (score 2):

`/make /outdir path`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the output of `vb6.exe /?`

[image]