# Can MSbuild.exe be used for for VB6 code?

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, vb6

I have an requirement to use the Msbuild to build the dotnet code and move the code to a specified location.

For dotnet framework 2.0 and above I am able to do it as I can specify the targetframework in build.proj file, but I am not sure how to make a build.proj file for vb6 code ?

If this is possible what will the build.proj file will look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VB 6 is not .net and isn't supported by MSbuild out of the box. If you need to automate the building of VB6 code then you [can call VB6.EXE directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444505/what-are-the-command-line-options-for-the-vb6-ide-compiler) passing in the .vbp project file.

However if you want to make things consistent then you can use the [MSBuild extension pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com) this contains support for [building VB6 code via MSBuild](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/c68d1d6c-b0bc-c944-e1a2-1ad4f0c28d3c.htm)

You'll still need to make sure that the VB6 IDE is installed on the machine performing the build

Comment: thnx James, I am runnning the  build.exe pragmatically in c# and I have used a build.proj file to copy the code to a location from where it will be deployed to the server by other team. Currently MSbuild.exe is able to copy the code and it runs successfully. DO you see any problem in this or am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Automating stuff is always good. The main issue with vb6 builds is making sure you trap any error codes.

Comment: Thnx, Our sole purpose for vb6 code is to copy to a location as it is compiled and we need not to built it. As the code is built before it is moved to dimensions (code management tool). we just need to move it to the server. thnx a ton

Comment: MSBuild extension pack links are dead